# HIbernate creates table without foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, foreign-key-relationship, one-to-one

I'm trying to create OneToOne unidirectional relationship with shared Primary Key. According to [this](http://websystique.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-unidirectional-with-shared-primary-key-annotation-example/) tutorial all I need is a @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation on parent side:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name="cities")
 public class City {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue
 @Column(name = "city_id")
 private int id;

 @Column
 private String name;   

 @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
 private Mayor mayor;
}

 @Entity
 @Table(name="mayors") 
 public class Mayor {

 @Id
 @Column
 private int id;

 @Column
 private String firstName;

 @Column
 private String secondName;
}
```

Hibernate successfully build tables, but mayors table has no foreign key.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: cities table should have foreign key not mayor table.

Comment: cities also have no any foreign key